# Anyone able to derive the following Riemann invariant relations?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hyperbolic-equations

The following was taken from Toro's Riemann Solvers and Numerical Methods for Fluid Dynamics, Equation (2.123) in Chapter 2.

It states that for a general quasi-linear hyperbolic system $U_t + A(U)U_x = 0$ with $U = [u_1, u_2, ..., u_m]^T$, where $\lambda_i$ and $R_i = [r_1^{(i)}, r_2^{(i)}, ..., r_m^{(i)}]^T$ correspond to the $i^{th}$ eigenvalue and right eigenvector respectively, the following relations hold true across the $i^{th}$ wave structure:

$$\frac{du_1}{r_1^{(i)}} = \frac{du_2}{r_2^{(i)}} = ... = \frac{du_m}{r_m^{(i)}}$$

Of note, the Riemann invariants *along* the $i^{th}$ characteristic can be obtained using the left eigenvectors of the Jacobian matrix $A(U)$, shown below for a general quasi-linear hyperbolic system.

$L_iA=\lambda_iL_i$ where $L_i$ is the $i^{th}$ left eigenvector.

Consider the following,

$L_iU_t + \lambda_iL_iU_x$

$=L_i(U_t+\lambda_iU_x)$

$=L_i(-AU_x+\lambda_iU_x)$

$=(-L_iA+\lambda_iL_i)U_x = 0$

since $L_iA=\lambda_iL_i$

$\therefore L_iU_t + \lambda_iL_iU_x = 0$

Let $L_i^T = \nabla{Q_i}$ where $\nabla(*) = [\partial{(*)}/\partial{u_1}, ..., \partial{(*)}/\partial{u_m}]$ and $Q_i$ is some scalar function,

$\nabla{Q_i} \cdot U_t + \lambda_i\nabla{Q_i} \cdot U_x = 0$

Expanding the dot products and applying chain rule,

$$\frac{\partial{Q_i}}{\partial{t}} + \lambda_i\frac{\partial{Q_i}}{\partial{x}} = 0$$

$$\frac{dQ_i}{dt} = 0 \text{ along } \frac{dx}{dt} = \lambda_i$$

Hence, by using $L_i^T = \nabla{Q_i}$, one is able to obtain $Q_i$ for the Riemann invariants *along* the $i^{th}$ characteristic. However, how do I derive the Riemann invariant relations involving the right eigenvectors *across* the $i^{th}$ characteristic?

Comment: Have you even attempted a proof? I would hope you did at least that.  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I am able to obtain the Riemann invariants using left eigenvectors, for say, the 1D Euler equations. But I'm not sure how this general relation was derived in the first place.

Comment: Great!  That would be helpful to show that you have made an effort, and likely, very helpful.  Can you edit your question to include in an edit to your post what you obtained?  That would be great!

Comment: I have added what I know about using the left eigenvectors to obtain the Riemann invariants.

Comment: Thanks for having done so! +1

Answer (score 1):

Eq. (2.123) of Toro is a definition of the so-called *Generalised Riemann Invariants*. I will briefly present the theory by using the notations in OP. I am using the book *Numerical Approximation of Hyperbolic Systems of Conservation Laws* by Godlewski and Raviart (Springer, 1996), Section 3.2 p. 53.

**Definition.** A smooth scalar function $U \mapsto Q_i(U)$ is called a $i$-Riemann invariant if it satisfies $ \nabla Q_i \cdot R_i = 0$ for all $U$ in ${\bf R}^m$, where $R_i$ is the $i$th right eigenvector.

Now, if we write the [Lagrange-Charpit equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) for $\nabla Q_i \cdot R_i = 0$, we find
$$
\frac{dU}{d\xi} = R_i
$$
where we have introduced the parametrization $U = U(\xi)$ to write $\frac{d}{d\xi} Q_i = \nabla Q_i \cdot \frac{d}{d\xi} U$. The proposed identity
$$
\frac{d u_1}{r_1^{(i)}} = \dots = \frac{d u_m}{r_m^{(i)}}
$$
is only a parameter-invariant form of the latter equation.

Note: if we insert the above parametrization in the PDE system $U_t + A(U)U_x = 0$, then we find
$$
\left(\xi_t I + \xi_x A(U)\right) \frac{d U}{d\xi} = \left(\xi_t + \lambda_i \xi_x\right) R_i = 0
$$
where we have used $\frac{d}{d\xi} U = R_i$ and the definition of the eigenvector. Thus, we arrive at the scalar transport equation $\xi_t + \lambda_i \xi_x = 0$ for the parameter $\xi$, and the $i$-Riemann invariant satisfies the PDE $(\partial_t + \lambda_i\partial_x)Q_{i} = 0$ proposed in OP.